# PHP creating path and folders with variable names

Tags: php, html, variables, directory

In PHP I am trying to make a new database type folder for different people on sign up and add files.  I could easily create files and write to them but for some reason every time i try to have PHP create folders using the persons username variable as the path, all it does is create a folder named $username.

Here is my code cut down to the basics of that part.

```
<?php
$title = $_POST["title"];
$myFile = "/users/$username/title.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("There was an error in changing your title.  <br />");
$stringData = "$title\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

$template = $_POST["temp"];
$myFile = "$structure/template.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("There was an error in changing your template.  <br />");
$stringData = "$template\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: Where is the code to make the directory?

Comment: Have you tried breaking out the $username from the string: `$myFile = "/users/".$username."/title.txt";`

Comment: You should use `mkdir()` function before. http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: can you please provide the values for $username and $structure?

Comment: I said it above, but it just creates the path /users/$username/title.txt it doesn't put in the actual username for the file path. I tried mkdir at one point but that just made a directory named $username also.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<?php
$title = $_POST["title"];
$myFile = "/users/".$username."/title.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("There was an error in changing your title.  <br />");
$stringData = $title."\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

$template = $_POST["temp"];
$myFile = $structure."/template.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("There was an error in changing your template.  <br />");
$stringData = $template."\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, you do need to break out the variable (as Ben Griffiths mentioned) from the string and check it isn't empty. Also, make sure you do make the directory first created using mkdir() (aschuler mentioned this as well). The code, therefore, may look something like this but without knowing where $username, $structure, $title and $template come from, you may need to alter this a little:

```
<?php
$title = $_POST['title'];
if (trim($username) == '') {
    die("No username passed in!");
} else {
    $userdir = "/users".$username."/";
    mkdir($userdir);
    $fh = fopen($userdir."title.txt", 'w') or die("There was an error in changing your title.  <br />");

    $stringData = $title."\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
}

$template = $_POST['temp'];
if (trim($template) == '') {
    die("No template passed in!");
} else {
    $structdir = $structure."/";
    mkdir($structdir);
    $fh = fopen($structdir."template.txt", 'w') or die("There was an error in changing your template.  <br />");

    $stringData = $template."\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
}

?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This should work, I can see that it should but for some reason even when I do this it creates the folder named $username or the code before that I used didn't create it at all. Do you think its my folder permissions?

Comment: Unlikely. I've ran the script on my server and while yes, I did have to change the permissions in the folder I was running the script in to 0755, when it did work, it created the directories with the $username variable correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that this `/users/$username/title.txt` create exactly `/users/$username/title.txt`

so Your problem is you need to catch $username first, I don't know how your code look but maybe this?

```
<?php $username=$_SESSION['username']; //retrieve the username 
    //rest of your code 
    $myFile = "/users/$username/title.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("There was an error in changing your title.  <br />");
$stringData = "$title\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

$template = $_POST["temp"];
$myFile = "$structure/template.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("There was an error in changing your template.  <br />");
$stringData = "$template\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```